# Converter milhões de STRING para INT - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, int

Tenho uma string `123.456.789` e ao usar parseInt está retornando `123456`, como fazer para para retornar `123456789` ?

Comment: Retire os pontos com replace.

Comment: Provavelmente ele está considerando o último ponto como ponto decimal e daí quando você converte para inteiro ele despreza a parte decimal ficando apenas a parte inteira.

Answer (score 3):

Neste exemplo, primeiro fiz a formatação, removendo o pontos, em seguida fiz a conversão.

```js
var numeroFormatado = `123.456.789`.replace(/\./g, ``)

numero = parseInt(numeroFormatado)

console.log(numero)
```

Comment: Exatamente, o ultimo ponto é visto como casa decimal na língua inglesa